Python Azure OpenAI Embeddings Error ServiceUnavailableError: The server is overloaded or not ready yet
I recently deployed a text-embedding-3-small model (successfully) on Azure OpenAI Studio.
I have been working with this model and the Python API (openai library) a few weeks without problem. But, I am experiencing the following error:
ServiceUnavailableError: The server is overloaded or not ready yet.

Here is the code to reproduce the error (you need an ada-3 model deployed):
import openai
deployment_id='text-embedding-3-small'
openai.api_type = "azure"
openai.api_key='<your API key>'
openai.api_base='<your model endpoint>'
openai.api_version='2023-12-01-preview'

def get_embedding(text):
    embedding = openai.Embedding.create(
    deployment_id=deployment_id,
    input=text
    )["data"][0]["embedding"]
    return embedding

get_embedding("home")

Does anybody know what can we do to mitigate this issue? (if it can be)
Full error trace:
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ServiceUnavailableError                   Traceback (most recent call last)
<command-1288227895963234> in <cell line: 1>()
----> 1 get_embedding('house')

<command-3196233496565426> in get_embedding(text)
      1 def get_embedding(text):
----> 2     embedding = openai.Embedding.create(
      3     deployment_id=deployment_id,
      4     input=text
      5     )["data"][0]["embedding"]

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1cf91c3b-2e72-4479-bac6-b7820038bdd2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_resources/embedding.py in create(cls, *args, **kwargs)
     31         while True:
     32             try:
---> 33                 response = super().create(*args, **kwargs)
     34 
     35                 # If a user specifies base64, we'll just return the encoded string.

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1cf91c3b-2e72-4479-bac6-b7820038bdd2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_resources/abstract/engine_api_resource.py in create(cls, api_key, api_base, api_type, request_id, api_version, organization, **params)
    153         )
    154 
--> 155         response, _, api_key = requestor.request(
    156             "post",
    157             url,

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1cf91c3b-2e72-4479-bac6-b7820038bdd2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py in request(self, method, url, params, headers, files, stream, request_id, request_timeout)
    297             request_timeout=request_timeout,
    298         )
--> 299         resp, got_stream = self._interpret_response(result, stream)
    300         return resp, got_stream, self.api_key
    301 

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1cf91c3b-2e72-4479-bac6-b7820038bdd2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py in _interpret_response(self, result, stream)
    708         else:
    709             return (
--> 710                 self._interpret_response_line(
    711                     result.content.decode("utf-8"),
    712                     result.status_code,

/local_disk0/.ephemeral_nfs/envs/pythonEnv-1cf91c3b-2e72-4479-bac6-b7820038bdd2/lib/python3.9/site-packages/openai/api_requestor.py in _interpret_response_line(self, rbody, rcode, rheaders, stream)
    753 
    754         if rcode == 503:
--> 755             raise error.ServiceUnavailableError(
    756                 "The server is overloaded or not ready yet.",
    757                 rbody,

ServiceUnavailableError: The server is overloaded or not ready yet.

